# Issue with div in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, division

I am learning basic assembly using NASM and stumbled on an issue in the `div` of two numbers.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
section .data 
   msg1 db "Enter first digit  (a): ", 0
   len1 equ $- msg1 

   msg2 db "Enter second digit (b): ", 0 
   len2 equ $- msg2 

   newLine db "",0xA

   msg3 db "The division (a/b) is: ",0
   len3 equ $- msg3

section .bss
   num1 resb 2 
   num2 resb 2 
   res resb 1   

section .text
   global _start
    
_start:
    mov eax, 4         
    mov ebx, 1         
    mov ecx, msg1         
    mov edx, len1 
    int 0x80                

    mov eax, 3 
    mov ebx, 0  
    mov ecx, num1 
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80            

    mov eax, 4        
    mov ebx, 1         
    mov ecx, msg2          
    mov edx, len2         
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 3  
    mov ebx, 0  
    mov ecx, num2 
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80        

    mov eax, 4         
    mov ebx, 1         
    mov ecx, msg3          
    mov edx, len3         
    int 0x80
    
    mov ax, [num1]     ; Load the 16-bit value from num1
    sub ax, '0'

    mov eax, 0         ; Clear the upper 16 bits of eax
    mov [num1], ax     ; Store the result back in num1

    mov bx, [num2]     ; Load the 16-bit value from num2
    sub bx, '0'

    mov ebx, 0         ; Clear the upper 16 bits of eax
    mov [num2], bx     ; Store the result back in num2

    mov eax, [num1]
    sub eax, '0'

    mov ebx, [num2]
    sub ebx, '0'

    mov edx, 0
    div bx     ; eax = quotient, edx = remainder
    add ax, '0'

    mov [res], ax

    mov eax, 4        
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, res         
    mov edx, 1
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1  
    mov ecx, newLine 
    mov edx, 1
    int 0x80   

    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

And the output generated is

[image: output]

I did some research on the previous similar questions on `div` on stack overflow but to no avail and also did the reading on google but couldn't solve the issue.

please help, I am stuck on this since last night

Comment: Your loads and stores don't match the space that was reserved at the target locations

Comment: @harold ya sorry about that i was experimenting and, I forgot change it back. The same issue still exists even after the change.

Comment: Are they now the way you intended them to be? They still don't match though, eg `num1` has 2 bytes of memory allocated for it but `mov eax, [num1]` loads 4 bytes

Comment: @harold I did some changes now the output comes out to be 1 no mater what the number. Sorry, but I am kinda new to this.

Comment: ` mov eax, 0         ; Clear the upper 16 bits of eax` - this clears the whole eax, not just the upper 16-bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> mov ax, [num1]     ; Load the 16-bit value from num1
> sub ax, '0'
> mov eax, 0         ; Clear the upper 16 bits of eax
> mov [num1], ax     ; Store the result back in num1
> ```

Although *num1* had 2 bytes reserved, only the first byte is important for your calculation. Remember you were asking the user for a **single digit** number? Subtracting '0' will correctly convert from the character ["0","9"] into the value [0,9], but if you move zero into EAX you will lose that value immediately. The solution is to write the following and with no need to store it back in *num1*:

```
movzx eax, byte [num1]
sub   eax, '0'
```

---

> ```
> mov bx, [num2]     ; Load the 16-bit value from num2
> sub bx, '0'
> mov ebx, 0         ; Clear the upper 16 bits of eax
> mov [num2], bx     ; Store the result back in num2
> ```

Same as above, but keep the result in EBX

---

> ```
> mov eax, [num1]
> sub eax, '0'
> ```

Here you are reading 4 bytes where you had only 2 bytes stored. Plus you are erroneously subtracting '0', *again*. The conversion had already been done before! This part can be removed.

---

> ```
> mov ebx, [num2]
> sub ebx, '0'
> ```

Similar to the first number, you can remove this part too.

---

> ```
> mov edx, 0
> div bx     ; eax = quotient, edx = remainder
> add ax, '0'
> mov [res], ax
> ```

From your comment, it seems like you want dword-sized division, but then you need to write `div ebx`. And since the *res* variable had only 1 byte reserved, you should never try to store 2 bytes in it.

All together:

```
    ...
    
    movzx eax, byte [num1]
    sub   eax, '0'
    movzx ebx, byte [num2]
    sub   ebx, '0'
    jz    Quit            ; You should not divide by zero!
    xor   edx, edx
    div   ebx             ; -> EAX = quotient, EDX = remainder
    add   eax, '0'        ; Convert to character
    mov   [res], al
    
    ...
    
Quit:
    mov   eax, 1
    int   0x80
```